# Finding the same elements in two list in racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket, set-intersection

Assume `(list 'red 'blue 'green 'yellow)` and `(list 'black 'red 'orange 'green)`, then it should produce 2 since there are 2 same elements. I only know how to find the same elements in the exact same place as follows:

```
(define (helper l1 l2)
  (cond
    [(equal? l1) empty]
    [(equal? l2) empty]
    [(equal? (first l1) (first l2)) true]
    [else (rest l1) (rest l2)]))
```

Help please. :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you're not doing this as a homework exercise, here's Óscar López' code using Racket's [set library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html).

```lisp
#lang racket

(require racket/set)

(define number-same (compose1 length set-intersect))

(number-same '(red blue green yellow)
             '(black red orange green))
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, test it: throws an error. See my answer for a correct implementation that fixes the mistakes.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Works fine here. Are you using the most recent Racket version? Lists [are sets](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html) BTW.

Comment: Hmmm, indeed this seems to be a version-related issue, I was using v5.3.6. In previous releases of Racket you had to explicitly convert the input lists into sets, before calling `set-intersect` on them. Oh well, at least I can say that my solution is backward-compatible :P

Answer (score -1):

this my code for finding the same elements in two list on racket

```
(define (cek x y)
 (cond
 [(null? y) 0]
 [(eq? x (car y)) (+ 1 (cek x (cdr y)))]
 [else (cek x (cdr y))]
 )
)
(define (sifat x y)
 (cond
 [(null? x) 0]
 [else (+ (cek (car x) y) (sifat (cdr x) y))]
 )
)
```